# Desktop equivalent to iOS Safari scalling page to viewport width?

Tags: css, css-transforms

is there a CSS trick that can mimic the way iOS Safari scales the entire contents of a page to the width of the viewport in a desktop browser? This is for a prototype so it doesn't need to be the "proper" way of doing something and can just work in one browser (preferably Chrome or Safari).

Basically I want to code something at one size (1920px x 1080px to be exact) and then have everything scale to the width of the browser if it's smaller or bigger than that, without having to specify all my dimensions in percentages. Is there something I can do with 3d transforms or setting the whole page to be a canvas (I don't know enough about either to know if this is a dumb question or not...)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this may be what you are looking for:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This tag will force the browser to give the page the same width as the screen / viewport size. It's important to note this only works well for pages that are built in a responsive manner. If you are using fixed pixel values for everything (it kinda sounds like that may be the case?), this probably won't work very well.

The other option: you could size everything using relative units (instead of percentages), such as `em` or `rem`, and then scale down the overall `font-size` at certain viewport widths. Like so:

```
html {
  font-size: 65%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  html {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}

.my-element {
  width: 2rem;
}
```

In this case `my-element` will have a different width at different viewport sizes.